# RealTime Calculations based on inputs and clicked radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a real time calculator for Net-Profit based on the trasaction, of the given quantity at given buy and sell price and it has 2 radio buttons as inputs.

What is happening is, I have to hit enter after putting values and selecting the button.

Where as what I want is, as soon as I input values and select radio button it should calculate the values.

Pl help me correct my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Brokerage Calculator</title>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Buy Price
<input type="number" min="0" id="bp"><br /> 
Sell Price
<input type="number" min="0" id="sp"><br /> 
Qty:
<input type="number" min="0" id="qty"><br /> 
NSE: 
<input name="exchname" id="nse" value="0.0000325" type="radio"  checked="checked"><br />
BSE: 
<input name="exchname" id="bse" value="0.0000275" type="radio"><br />
Turnover:
<span id="turnover">0</span><br /> 
Brokerage:
<span id="brokerage">0</span><br />
Security Transction Tax:
<span id="stt">0</span><br />
Total Tran Charges:
<span id="ttc">0</span><br />
SEBI Charges:
<span id="sebi">0</span><br />
Service Tax:
<span id="servtax">0</span><br />
Stamp Duty:
<span id="std">0</span><br />
Total Brokerage + Taxes:
<span id="ttx">0</span><br />
Net Profit:
<span id="pnl">0</span><br />

<script>

$('input').keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes

    var buyPrice = parseFloat($('#bp').val()); // get value of field
    var sellPrice = parseFloat($('#sp').val()); // convert it to a float
    var quantity = parseFloat($('#qty').val());
    var turnoverValue = (buyPrice + sellPrice) * quantity;
    var sttValue = sellPrice * quantity * 0.025 / 100;
    var sebiValue = turnoverValue * 0.0002 / 100;

    var stdValue = 0.00002 * turnoverValue;
    var excrate = document.querySelector('input[name="exchname"]:checked').value;

    if(buyPrice<166.67){
        var brkgbp = 0.05;
    } else {
            var brkgbp = buyPrice * 0.03 / 100;
    }

    if(sellPrice<166.67){
        var brkgsp = 0.05;
    } else {
            var brkgsp = sellPrice * 0.03 / 100;
    }

    var brokerageValue = (brkgbp + brkgsp) * quantity;
    var ttcValue = excrate * turnoverValue;
    var servtaxValue = (brokerageValue + ttcValue + sebiValue) * 15 / 100;
    var ttxValue = brokerageValue + sttValue + ttcValue + sebiValue + servtaxValue + stdValue;
    var pnlValue = ((sellPrice - buyPrice) * quantity) - ttxValue;
    $('#turnover').html(turnoverValue.toFixed(2));
    $('#brokerage').html(brokerageValue.toFixed(2));
    $('#stt').html(sttValue.toFixed(2));
    $('#sebi').html(sebiValue.toFixed(2));
    $('#servtax').html(servtaxValue.toFixed(2));
    $('#ttc').html(ttcValue.toFixed(2));
    $('#std').html(stdValue.toFixed(2));
    $('#ttx').html(ttxValue.toFixed(2));
    $('#pnl').html(pnlValue.toFixed(2));
});

<script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you forgot to close the script tag?

```
<script> ... </script>
```

Also, use

```
var buyPrice = parseFloat($('#bp').val()) || 0;
```

to initialize with a default value, so you don't get NaN

If you want the values to change when you reselect an option in the radio buttons, use:

```
function calculate(){ // run anytime the value changes
    ....
}
$('input').on('keyup', calculate);
$('input').on('click', calculate);
```

EDIT: I made a JSfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/v3qd7b26/

Comment: Thanks for the help :)  I've combined all three answers and it is working as my need. Thank you guys 

https://jsfiddle.net/neonirav/xetjhm6u/2/

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issue in your code

**1.** You are missing the `/` in the script tag at the end. It should be `</script>` instead of `<script>`.

**2.** You need to ensure that the values entered are valid numbers only and then only proceed further, you can validate that using `isNaN` function in javascript

`if(!isNaN(buyPrice) && !isNaN(sellPrice) && !isNaN(quantity)){`

**3.**
Also, for checkbox need to add another **selector**. So you can create a common function and call it.

```
$("input").keyup(calculate);
$("input:checked").keyup(calculate);
```

**Complete code:**

```js
$("input").keyup(calculate);
$("input:checked").keyup(calculate);

function calculate(){ // run anytime the value changes
 
  
  
    var buyPrice = parseFloat($('#bp').val()); // get value of field
    var sellPrice = parseFloat($('#sp').val()); // convert it to a float
    var quantity = parseFloat($('#qty').val());
  if(!isNaN(buyPrice) && !isNaN(sellPrice) && !isNaN(quantity)){
  
    var turnoverValue = (buyPrice + sellPrice) * quantity;
    var sttValue = sellPrice * quantity * 0.025 / 100;
    var sebiValue = turnoverValue * 0.0002 / 100;

    var stdValue = 0.00002 * turnoverValue;
    var excrate = document.querySelector('input[name="exchname"]:checked').value;

    if(buyPrice<166.67){
        var brkgbp = 0.05;
    } else {
            var brkgbp = buyPrice * 0.03 / 100;
    }

    if(sellPrice<166.67){
        var brkgsp = 0.05;
    } else {
            var brkgsp = sellPrice * 0.03 / 100;
    }

    var brokerageValue = (brkgbp + brkgsp) * quantity;
    var ttcValue = excrate * turnoverValue;
    var servtaxValue = (brokerageValue + ttcValue + sebiValue) * 15 / 100;
    var ttxValue = brokerageValue + sttValue + ttcValue + sebiValue + servtaxValue + stdValue;
    var pnlValue = ((sellPrice - buyPrice) * quantity) - ttxValue;
    $('#turnover').html(turnoverValue.toFixed(2));
    $('#brokerage').html(brokerageValue.toFixed(2));
    $('#stt').html(sttValue.toFixed(2));
    $('#sebi').html(sebiValue.toFixed(2));
    $('#servtax').html(servtaxValue.toFixed(2));
    $('#ttc').html(ttcValue.toFixed(2));
    $('#std').html(stdValue.toFixed(2));
    $('#ttx').html(ttxValue.toFixed(2));
    $('#pnl').html(pnlValue.toFixed(2));
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Buy Price
<input type="number" min="0" id="bp"><br /> 
Sell Price
<input type="number" min="0" id="sp"><br /> 
Qty:
<input type="number" min="0" id="qty"><br /> 
NSE: 
<input name="exchname" id="nse" value="0.0000325" type="radio"  checked="checked"><br />
BSE: 
<input name="exchname" id="bse" value="0.0000275" type="radio"><br />
Turnover:
<span id="turnover">0</span><br /> 
Brokerage:
<span id="brokerage">0</span><br />
Security Transction Tax:
<span id="stt">0</span><br />
Total Tran Charges:
<span id="ttc">0</span><br />
SEBI Charges:
<span id="sebi">0</span><br />
Service Tax:
<span id="servtax">0</span><br />
Stamp Duty:
<span id="std">0</span><br />
Total Brokerage + Taxes:
<span id="ttx">0</span><br />
Net Profit:
<span id="pnl">0</span><br />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)  I've combined all three answers and it is working as my need. Thank you guys 

https://jsfiddle.net/neonirav/xetjhm6u/2/

Answer (score 1):

Your closing script tag is missing the `/`, i.e. `</script>`

For your inputs, you're checking for the release of a keyboard key, which wouldn't fire for clicking radio buttons.  Since you're checking to see if the value of the input has changed, you should change `$('input').keyup` to `$('input').change`.

**edit:** of course, you should do the NaN checking as well, as the other answers indicated - but the problem you described is solved by using the `change` event.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)  I've combined all three answers and it is working as my need. Thank you guys 

https://jsfiddle.net/neonirav/xetjhm6u/2/